# Remove outliers grouped by factor in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following function which can remove outliers n stdevs over or below the average for a given column `attr` from the dataframe:

```
remove_outliers <- function(df,attr,n){
  outliersgone <- df[df[,attr]<=(mean(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)+n*sd(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)) & df[,attr]>=(mean(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)-n*sd(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)),]
  return(outliersgone)
}
```

Now, in fact I am interested in a dataframe like `iris` where it would be best to first group by `Species` and then remove the outliers. That is, remove any instances of `setosa` species that are more than n stdevs above or below the mean, **for that species**, for the chosen `attr`.

I tried to code this as follows using `dplyr`:

```
remove_outliers_grouped <- function(df,attr,n,Factor=NULL){
  outliers_grouped_gone <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by_at(Factor)) %>% remove_outliers(.,attr,n)
  return(outliers_grouped_gone)
}
```

Now we can try

```
irisG <- remove_outliers_grouped(df=iris, attr="Petal.Length", n=1.2, Factor="Species")
irisG2 <- remove_outliers_grouped(df=iris, attr="Petal.Length", n=1.2)
```

But the two dataframes are identical. i.e., though no error message shows, factor grouping has not occurred even when I supplied `Factor="Species"` as an argument. How can I fix this?

(A solution which sticks to base R and dplyr would be ideal...)

Comment: Use `%>% do(remove_outliers(...))`, as `do` will implement the grouping so your function does not need to. (As it stands, your function gets called once with all data regardless of grouping.)

Comment: There is no warning because `group_by_at(NULL)` doesn't return any warnings.. i..e `iris%>% group_by_at(NULL)` (it simply doesn't have any grouping attributes)

Comment: @r2evans that doesn't appear to introduce grouping by factor any more than it did without ```do```.

Comment: @akrun Yes I expected that behaviour, that's why I wrote the function like it is. What I didn't expect is that it would fail to group by Species when I put in "Species", but not return an error message

Comment: Mobeus, my point is that `remove_outliers` in a pipe is ignoring grouping, regardless of how you construct the groups. Compare `group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>% nrow` with `group_by(mtcars, cyl) %>% do(data.frame(nrow(.)))` (framed only because `do` for some reason requires it). In the latter, `do(...)` enforces the grouping so that the inner code only sees one group at a time (and can therefore be completely ignorant to the presence of groups).

Comment: @r2evans OK thanks, I can see that now though I'm not sure why. Question then is how to fix it...

Comment: *"not sure why"* that `%>% remove_outliers(...)` does not work? Because grouping is merely an attribute on the data, and your function is ignoring the attributes. It's an architectural decision of `dplyr` functions, preserving as much compatibility with non-`dplyr` functions as possible. I think supporting the `do`-wrapper is a fairly good workaround, not requiring all other functions manage `dplyr`-groups (which can be a nightmare). *"how to fix it"* ... is there a reason `do(remove_outliers(.,attr,n))` is not a fix?

Comment: @r2evans I tried repeating the (reproducible) experiment in my OP after replacing ```remove_outliers(.,attr,n)``` with ```do(remove_outliers(.,attr,n))``` and there was no change. (That's to say, no error message, but grouping is still ignored.) If you want to see the output expected, the answer below produces it (though it rewrites way more of my code) taking n=0.1

Comment: Do you know that `as.data.frame` strips any attributes it doesn't know about? Your (completely unnecessary) use of `as.data.frame` is negating `group_by`

Comment: @r2evans Thanks I didn't really know that, but when I remove that coercion I get Error ```'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-write your function in the following way, tidying some expressions (you can write the `... <= ... & ... >= ...` expression more succinctly using `abs`) and allowing for quoted and unquoted column names (using non-standard evaluation):

```r
remove_outlier <- function(df, var, n) {
    var <- rlang::parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(var)))
    df %>% filter(abs(!!var - mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE)) <= n * sd(!!var, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

A non-grouping use-case would look like this

```r
iris %>% remove_outlier(Petal.Length, 0.1)
# Or quoted: iris %>% remove_outlier("Petal.Length", 0.1)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#2          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#3          5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor
#4          5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
#5          5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
#6          5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor
```

Grouping is done outside of the function

```r
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% remove_outlier(Petal.Length, 0.1) %>% ungroup()
## A tibble: 11 x 5
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#1          6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#2          6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#3          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica 
#4          6.8         3            5.5         2.1 virginica 
#5          6.5         3            5.5         1.8 virginica 
#6          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1 virginica 
#7          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2 virginica 
#8          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4 virginica 
#9          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4 virginica 
#10          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8 virginica 
#11          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4 virginica
```

The return `tibble` contains the original data with outliers removed *by group*.

---

### Update 1

#### Re comment 1

To remove the `rlang` dependency, we can define a function that takes only quoted column names, and turn those into symbols using `sym`; `sym` is exported by `dplyr`, so we don't need an explicit `library(rlang)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
remove_outlier_quoted <- function(df, var, n) {
    df %>% filter(abs(!!sym(var) - mean(!!sym(var), na.rm = TRUE)) <= n * sd(!!sym(var), na.rm = TRUE))
}
iris %>% remove_outlier_quoted("Petal.Length", 0.1)
```

#### Re comment 2

Personally, I'd keep the grouping outside of the function; IMO this would be the more `dplyr`-canonical way (for example, there's no `summarise_grouped` function, instead `dplyr` requires the explicit use of `group_by` and `summarise`), and is probably easier to read. But I guess it comes down to a matter of preference. You can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
remove_outlier_grouped <- function(df, var, group, n) {
    var <- rlang::parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(var)))
    group <- rlang::parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(group)))
    df %>%
        group_by(!!group) %>%
        filter(abs(!!var - mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE)) <= n * sd(!!var, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        ungroup()
}
iris %>% remove_outlier_grouped(Petal.Length, Species, 0.1)
# Or: iris %>% remove_outlier_grouped("Petal.Length", "Species", 0.1)
```

Both the `var` and `group` arguments of `remove_outlier_grouped` can be quoted or unquoted. To remove the `rlang` dependency, see the "Re comment 1".

### Update 2

To address your last comments, here's an option where I define two functions. In a hypothetical R package, the "heavy lifter" `remove_outlier` does not get exported, whereas the wrapper function `remove_outlier_grouped` does get exported. All argument checks are done in `remove_outlier_grouped`. In this example I use NSE, i.e. the function arguments *must* be unquoted and get defused using `enquo` inside `remove_outlier_grouped`. (If you wanted to allow for both quoted and unquoted arguments, some extra care needs to be taken with quoting and evaluating, which would make this example unnecessarily complex. You can see my original post for how this is done in general.)

```r
#' This function does not get exported; var must be a symbol
#' Argument checking has to happen in the parent
remove_outlier <- function(df, var, n) {
    df %>% filter(
        abs(!!var - mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE)) <= n * sd(!!var, na.rm = TRUE))
}

#' This function gets exported as a user function; all argument checks
#' happen here
remove_outlier_grouped <- function(df, var, group, n) {
    var <- enquo(var)
    if (rlang::quo_is_null(var) | rlang::quo_is_missing(var))
        stop("Must provide column")
    group <- enquo(group)
    if (!rlang::quo_is_null(group) & !rlang::quo_is_missing(group)) {
        df %>% group_by(!!group) %>% remove_outlier(var, n) %>% ungroup()
    } else {
        df %>% remove_outlier(var, n)
    }
}

# With grouping
remove_outlier_grouped(iris, Petal.Length, Species, 0.1)

# Without grouping
remove_outlier_grouped(iris, Petal.Length, n = 0.1)
#Or: remove_outlier_grouped(iris, Petal.Length, NULL, 0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good solution. I'm not very familiar with ```rlang``` but I suppose it satisfies my condition since it's a dependency of ```dplyr```. Could this be done without ```rlang``` if I don't mind necessitating quoted or unquoted column names? (e.g. our input must be of form ```var="Petal.Length"```. Or, input must be ```var=Petal.Length```. Whichever is easier to program)

Comment: Also, *with* rlang, I'd like to wrap the grouping outliers command in a function :

```remove_outlier_grouped <- function(df, var, n, factor){
  Factor <- rlang::parse_expr(quo_name(enquo(factor)));
  
  df %>% group_by(!!Factor) %>% remove_outlier(var = var, n = n) %>% ungroup()
}```. but for some reason, when I then try to test ```remove_outlier_grouped(df=iris, var=Petal.Length, n=1.2, factor="Species")```, it errors with ```object 'Petal.Length' not found```. Can we fix this?

Comment: @MobeusZoom Sure, I've made an edit to address both comments. Please take a look.

Comment: thank you! That's a big help. What's the most straightforward way to account for the ```group=NULL``` possibility i.e. let the user choose not to group at all, within the function? I found using ```if(length(group)==0)``` (after ```rlang::parse_expr```) as the condition and then more or less repeating the required code bits in each condition was the best way I could come up with--is this what you'd suggest?

Comment: You're very welcome @MobeusZoom. To check for a non-`NA` or non-`NULL` function argument I'd use `!is.na(x))` or `!is.null(x)`. In this case however, I would handle grouping outside of the function. One of the reasons being that I'd exactly want to avoid the kind of argument checking that you're trying to implement. Out of curiosity: Can I ask why you're so opposed to using the `group_by` plus `custom_function` approach? If it was me, I would do the following: Define a function `remove_outlier` (as def'ed above), that does exactly one thing: filter rows based on outliers from one column. [...]

Comment: [continued] `remove_outlier` does the "heavy lifting" (outlier ID and filtering) but no grouping. Then define a convenience function `remove_outlier_grouped` that essentially does `df  %>% group_by(group) %>% remove_outlier(...) %>% ungroup()`. That convenience function can handle the argument checking, and default to `remove_outlier` if `group` is `NA`. This approach has advantages: (1) Functions are easier to unit test, (2) code readability is increased, and (3) it's easy to extend `remove_outlier` to e.g. include other outlier detection methods without having to touch the rest of your code.

Comment: [continued] This might be a bit of overkill for such a simple example, but if your functions get "heavier" and more complex, modularising/recycling functionalities can be a real life-saver when debugging & testing your code.

Comment: I might be a little unclear...maybe you could edit this into your post (as a modification or continuation to your Re comment 2: pertains to the same issue). I should have used 'convenience function' instead of 'single function' earlier perhaps--I have nothing against calling ```remove_outlier``` in ```remove_outlier_grouped```. I just wanted a function I could call with all the relevant arguments and have it do all the work for the user i.e. want to get the right output from ```remove_outlier_grouped(iris, Petal.Length, Species, 0.1)``` in the end.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your post with the ```remove_outlier``` and ```remove_outlier_grouped``` you mean? Specifically I'm unclear how to implement the conditional.

Comment: @MobeusZoom I've edited my post to include a second update.

Comment: thanks for the help. I checked with ```microbenchmark``` and this is about 7x faster than the non-```rlang``` method below. (Interestingly, it seems to be slowed down a lot if I try using pure ```dplyr``` without ```rlang```--e.g. just use ```quo_name(enquo(group))``` followed by ```group_by_at```. Maybe the use of ```group_by_at``` with quoted name is the bottleneck there.) Anyway, as promised, I've chosen the most efficient answer as 'best'

Answer (score 1):

Up front:

1. Remove `as.data.frame`, add `do`.
2. Change from `df[,attr]` to `df[[attr]]`.

This answer tries to preserve your functions as much as possible. Having said that, I think @MauritsEvers' suggestion to shift to a more `rlang`-esque way of programmatic access to `dplyr` functionality is likely better in the long run. It has a little bit of a learning curve, but will pay off in the long run (e.g., with functions that behave more intuitively and correctly with `dplyr`).

### First: stop using `as.data.frame`

... and add `do` so the grouping is handled correctly, externally to your `remove_outliers` function.

If I `debug(remove_outliers_grouped)`, then run the first code, I see:

```r
debug(remove_outliers_grouped)
remove_outliers_grouped(df=iris, attr="Petal.Length", n=1.2, Factor="Species")
# debugging in: remove_outliers_grouped(df = iris, attr = "Petal.Length", n = 1.2, 
#     Factor = "Species")
# debug at #1: {
#     outliers_grouped_gone <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by_at(Factor)) %>% 
#         remove_outliers(., attr, n)
#     return(outliers_grouped_gone)
# }
# Browse[2]> 

df %>%
  group_by_at(Factor) %>%
  attributes(.)
# $names
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
# $row.names
#   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
#  [30]  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58
#  [59]  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87
#  [88]  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116
# [117] 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145
# [146] 146 147 148 149 150
# $groups
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Species          .rows
# * <fct>      <list<int>>
# 1 setosa            [50]
# 2 versicolor        [50]
# 3 virginica         [50]
# $class
# [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
# Browse[2]> 

as.data.frame(df %>%
  group_by_at(Factor)) %>%
  attributes(.)
# $class
# [1] "data.frame"
# $row.names
#   [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
#  [30]  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58
#  [59]  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87
#  [88]  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116
# [117] 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145
# [146] 146 147 148 149 150
# $names
# [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"
```

Notice how the `$groups` component is present in the first example and missing in the second? *That* is what is needed for `do` to do its thing.

This produces the following function (removing `as.data.frame` and adding `do`):

```r
remove_outliers_grouped <- function(df,attr,n,Factor=NULL){
  outliers_grouped_gone <- df %>% group_by_at(Factor) %>% do(remove_outliers(.,attr,n))
  return(outliers_grouped_gone)
}
```

This would work, but your `remove_outliers` function assumes only `data.frame` and not `tbl_df`. I recognize this is possibly why you thought to use `as.data.frame`, so

### Second: stop using `df[,attr]`

Either use `df[[attr]]` instead of `df[,attr]` or shift `as.data.frame` to *within* the first function. I'll demonstrate why `df[,attr]` fails (with `tbl_df`) and both options work.

```r
debug(remove_outliers)
remove_outliers_grouped(df=iris, attr="Petal.Length", n=1.2, Factor="Species")
# debugging in: remove_outliers(., attr, n)
# debug at #1: {
#     outliersgone <- df[df[, attr] <= (mean(df[, attr], na.rm = TRUE) + 
#         n * sd(df[, attr], na.rm = TRUE)) & df[, attr] >= (mean(df[, 
#         attr], na.rm = TRUE) - n * sd(df[, attr], na.rm = TRUE)), 
#         ]
#     return(outliersgone)
# }
# Browse[2]> 

df[,attr]
# # A tibble: 50 x 1
#    Petal.Length
#           <dbl>
#  1          1.4
#  2          1.4
#  3          1.3
#  4          1.5
#  5          1.4
#  6          1.7
#  7          1.4
#  8          1.5
#  9          1.4
# 10          1.5
# # ... with 40 more rows
# Browse[2]> 

as.data.frame(df)[,attr]
#  [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.4 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.3 1.4 1.7 1.5 1.7 1.5 1.0 1.7 1.9 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.4
# [30] 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.6 1.9 1.4 1.6 1.4 1.5 1.4

# Browse[2]> 
df[[attr]]
#  [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.4 1.1 1.2 1.5 1.3 1.4 1.7 1.5 1.7 1.5 1.0 1.7 1.9 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.4
# [30] 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.6 1.9 1.4 1.6 1.4 1.5 1.4
```

This is actually a common problem with functions that try to work interchangeably with `data.frame`, `tbl_df`, and `data.table` ...

Between the use of `df[[attr]]` and `df <- as.data.frame(df)` (and then the remaining unchanged code), I urge the first (the second has a bit more overhead converting back and forth, and knowing how to access the data securely without having to copy it around and change class and all sorts of thing ... is a good thing to be able to do.)

So let's change your first function to be:

```r
remove_outliers <- function(df,attr,n){
  outliersgone <- df[df[[attr]]<=(mean(df[[attr]],na.rm=TRUE)+n*sd(df[[attr]],na.rm=TRUE)) & df[[attr]]>=(mean(df[[attr]],na.rm=TRUE)-n*sd(df[[attr]],na.rm=TRUE)),]
  return(outliersgone)
}

remove_outliers_grouped(df=iris, attr="Petal.Length", n=1.2, Factor="Species")
# # A tibble: 121 x 5
# # Groups:   Species [3]
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#  6          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#  7          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#  8          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#  9          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# 10          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa 
# # ... with 111 more rows
```

(If you're curious, `df[,attr]` is ultimately `df[,attr,drop=TRUE]`, which is a default behavior that is both frustrating (to me) and different than the other frame-like objects, `tbl_df` and `data.table`. You can mimic the single-column-preserved behavior with `df[,attr,drop=FALSE]`, something I have peppered in much of my personal code and packages.)

---

A perhaps-simpler single-function implementation:

```r
remove_outliers2 <- function(df, attr, n) {
  mu <- mean(df[[attr]], na.rm=TRUE)
  sigma <- sd(df[[attr]], na.rm=TRUE)
  df[ between(df[[attr]], mu - n*sigma, mu + n*sigma), ]
}
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(remove_outliers2(., attr = "Petal.Length", n = 1.2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

or if you really want a single-function, here's a hack

```r
remove_outliers3 <- function(df, attr, n, Factor) {
  if (!missing(Factor)) {
    group_by_at(df, Factor) %>%
      do(remove_outliers3(., attr = attr, n = n))
  } else {
    mu <- mean(df[[attr]], na.rm=TRUE)
    sigma <- sd(df[[attr]], na.rm=TRUE)
    df[ between(df[[attr]], mu - n*sigma, mu + n*sigma), ]
  }
}

remove_outliers3(iris, "Petal.Length", n = 1.2, Factor = "Species")
```

though while the recursive nature of that works just fine, I think I prefer the previous version for its simplicity.

Comment: in this case I'm waiting for @MauritsEvers' answers to my questions in the comments. In particular, if it can be wrapped in a single function, and ideally without rlang (no interface is needed that handles quoted and unquoted names--though, I guess, I'm separately interested in that), I would use ```microbenchmark``` to test which approach is faster on a large simulated dataset and choose that as best answer. (Since both work and I can only pick one, I'll try to do so on basis of efficiency.) If no reply is forthcoming from him, I'll select this as the best answer

Comment: Good to know, that makes sense. My "not a rush" really was honest, I generally dislike the quick-prod *"hurry accept it now"* comments. I was balancing that with *"since you're here and you have many unaccepted answers to previous questions, ..."*.